# The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format. How to solve the init Swift Class error?

Tags: swift, class, init

I have the cell class:

```
// CELL

class CollectionCell: ScalingCarouselCell {


@IBOutlet weak var title: MLabelWhite!
@IBOutlet weak var name: MLabelWhite!
@IBOutlet weak var date: MLabelLight!
@IBOutlet weak var views: MLabelLight!
var id: String = ""

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    title.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    name.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    date.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    views.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    mainView = UIView(frame: contentView.bounds)
    contentView.addSubview(mainView)
    mainView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        mainView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
        mainView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
        mainView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
        mainView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor)
    ])
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
   super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
}
```

I have collection view with ids for each cell. When I press item id should be printed...
The problem is 100% with `init` :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellCollection", for: indexPath)
    if let scalingCell = cell as? CollectionCell {

// HERE 
// idList is ok. The problem is scalingCell.id is NOT SAVED

            scalingCell.id = idList[indexPath.row]
    }
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellCollection", for: indexPath)
    if let scalingCell = cell as? CollectionCell {
        print(scalingCell.id)
    }
}
```

**The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.**

Comment: What are override init(frame: CGRect) and required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) for?

Comment: What is ScalingCarouselCell?

Comment: Identical to your https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67731654/how-to-initialise-property-with-coder-in-swift/

Comment: Don't call `dequeueReusableCell(()` outside `cellForItemAt()`.

Comment: Which line is printing that error? I'd tend to say that's an error with parsing. And you have `print(error.localizedFormat)` somewhere, no? Where? Instead `print(error)` it should give more infos.

Comment: @matt , it's my post which I requested to delete. There were no responses so I did more detailed. All similar questions are related to JSON requests. Mine is 100% error of inside data.

Comment: @HarryJ **if let scalingCell = cell as? CollectionCell {** read again. Please.

Comment: @ElTomato to change the layouts? I have no clue what you mean) This is full description of usages.

Comment: @Larme any analogues for **dequeueReusableCell(()** ? The ID should be attached to the cell.

Comment: @Larme Tried try+catch+localized when we attach the value: scalingCell.id = ...
*'catch' block is unreachable because no errors are thrown in 'do' block*

Comment: HOW TO SAVE THE VALUE AT CELL CLASS?

Comment: There is no analogue, here you don't provide a cell, you retrieve one, so it should be: `if let cell = collectionViewView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? CollectionCell {}`. `do`/`catch` don't mean anything if there is no `try` (for a `throw`). It's like having a parachute in a car. Of course, it could save your life, but not in that case. Still, somewhere you did `print(error.localizedDescription)`, no? WHERE is that code? Is there a WebAPI Call somewhere? Reading JSON? Reading Plist? How is populated `idList`? Because `scalingCell.id = idList[indexPath.row]` shouldn't generate that error text.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is to `SAVE` `ID` state into the selected `CELL`.**

*If someone know how to solve this, please post an answer.*

Current solution is not to save the state into `cell.id`.
Just directly use `idList` with selected cell row id:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellCollection", for: indexPath)
    if cell is CollectionCell {
        print(idList[indexPath.row])
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I think this was always the right thing. Cells are reusable. They are user interface. They do not hold _data_.

Comment: As I said, don't use dequeue. Also, you don't need it here. Just `print(idList[indexPath.row])`. And this doesn't explain your error in console.